# ZXingScannerView is showing blank screen on coming back from next activity

Tags: android

I am using ZXingScannerView in my android app to scan qr code. When i open app and scan qr code it works fine and go to next activity after scanning required qr code  but when i press back button and again click on scanner button to scan again it shows blank white screen.
I am taking all required permissions.

```
public class OpenCamera extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
ZXingScannerView scannerView;
    String text="";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        setContentView(scannerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {
        try {
          text = result.getText();
            Toast.makeText(this, ""+text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            intent2.putExtra("code",text);
            setResult(RESULT_OK,intent2);
            finish();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.i("Open camera",e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String []{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        1);
                return;
            }
        }
        scannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        scannerView.startCamera();

    }



    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        scannerView.stopCamera();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        scannerView.stopCamera();
    }
}
```

Edit: build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.scanqr"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'com.chaos.view:pinview:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.budiyev.android:code-scanner:2.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
}
```

This is my code...

Comment: post your `build.gradle` file code

Comment: Also, try to stop `scannerView` camera inside onHandleResult method.

Comment: you may need to replace `mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);` with `mScannerView= (ZXingScannerView) findViewById(R.id.zxscan);`

Comment: I tried that too but still the same issue ...

Comment: I am not using any zxingscannerview in my xml file i am directly opening the camera...

Answer (score 0):

You have to call resumeCameraPreview() in onResume like this:

```
 scannerView.setResultHandler(this);
 scannerView.startCamera();
 scannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
```

And stop camera preview in onPause():

```
scannerView.stopCameraPreview();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:

```
zXingScannerView.startCamera(0);
or
zXingScannerView.startCamera(1);
```